# Подключение стилей к проекту

Tags: css

Есть код пульсирования текста. Могу ли я их каким либо образом запихуть в файлик, чтобы они лежали локально?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
 background: black;
 font-family: "Open Sans",  Impact;
}

.area {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6.5em;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: -7px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: blur .75s ease-out infinite;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff, 0px 0px 7px #fff;
}

@keyframes blur {
  from {
    text-shadow:0px 0px 10px #fff,
      0px 0px 10px #fff, 
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 50px #fff,
      0px 0px 50px #fff,
      0px 0px 50px #7B96B8,
      0px 0px 150px #7B96B8,
      0px 10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px 10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px 10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px 10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px -10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px -10px 100px #7B96B8;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="area">asd</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Кто они? Кого запихнуть? Ничего непонятно.

Comment: @MarkMinerov а если внимательнее глянуть? `@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);`

Comment: А если нормально описывать суть вопроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы имете в виду вот так?

fonts.css

```css
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFUZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFW50bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

main.css

```css
@import 'fonts.css'

body {
 background: black;
 font-family: "Open Sans",  Impact;
}

.area {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6.5em;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: -7px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: blur .75s ease-out infinite;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff, 0px 0px 7px #fff;
}

@keyframes blur {
  from {
    text-shadow:0px 0px 10px #fff,
      0px 0px 10px #fff, 
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 25px #fff,
      0px 0px 50px #fff,
      0px 0px 50px #fff,
      0px 0px 50px #7B96B8,
      0px 0px 150px #7B96B8,
      0px 10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px 10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px 10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px 10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px -10px 100px #7B96B8,
      0px -10px 100px #7B96B8;
  }
}
```

Comment: а `url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v17/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2)` как заменть ? скачиваю файлик и потом в `url` относительный путь?

Comment: Если подключать шрифты локально, это нужно делать с помощью `@font-face`